# Botón activa su función al segundo click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function my() {
var x = document.getElementById("open");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```css
.box-content-text-btn{
background: transparent; 
border: 0; 
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="my()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>botón</button>

    <div id='open' style='display: none;'>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sucede que cuando le doy click al botón para que abra el div no funciona, pero si le doy otro click funciona... es decir tengo que dar 2 clicks al botón para que active la función. quiero saber cómo puedo solucionar esto

Comment: he probado el código que muestras y funciona bien y muestra el contenido del div al primer click, de modo que debe ser algo más que tengas en el código lo que provoca el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi funciona bien

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x =document.getElementById("objetivo");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <body>
        <p id="demo">Click the button .</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <div id="objetivo" style='display: none;'>Hola mundo</div>
     </body>
  </html>
```